# drop event is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tav tag having some id in it.Hence when ever I am trying to drop something in it it should give an alert

```
<html>
  <head>



<!-- Load jQuery from Google's CDN -->

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Source our javascript file with the jQUERY code -->

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="fileupload"  id="drop-area">
 <img src="upload-here.png" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200" onclick='$("#fileupload").click()' id="clickImage">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="fileupload"  id='fileupload' style="display:none;" accept="image/*"/>


 </div>


   </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


  $( "#drop-area" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
   e.preventDefault();
  var image = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
  createFormData(image);
  }
});





  function createFormData(image) {
  var formImage = new FormData();
  formImage.append('userImage', image[0]);
  uploadFormData(formImage);
}

function uploadFormData(formData) {
  $.ajax({
  url: "upload.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  contentType:false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data){
    $('#drop-area').append(data);
  }
});
}
  });




</script>
</html>
```

this is my code what I have written but the problem is instead of giving alert it is showing the file in the browser....Help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting any error? Please check your browser console.

Comment: Yoou need to add jquery ui library

Comment: and do not keep 2 versions of `jquery`

Comment: @KaushikMaheta I have Updated my code still the erroe of not gone

Comment: @DibyenduKonar, Add jquery UI library. you can found example here. https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: @KaushikMaheta I have already added Them though not in this code but in the localhost I have added then hence the code in not working .. and the problem remains at the same position.Will You look at mey HTML struckture if there is any problem or not

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery ui Library first.

https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

```
  $( "#drop-area" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    //code here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) use this link for proper usage of droppable and you need to include jQueryUI js and also do not use two versions of jquery at a time